# Built React Native application cannot access local server running on emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I build Android application with `./android/gradlew assembleRelease` and install the built APK to Android emulator. However, I cannot access server in any of the following ways:

1. Using hostname IP `192.168.x.x`.
2. Using loopback address `10.0.2.2`.
3. Localhost address `127.0.0.1` (obviously).

It works when I start the application through `npx react-native start`, but not when building APK with `gradlew` and installing manually. Why?

I do use environment variables with `react-native-config` package, but they are set correctly in both cases.